# nuxt-optimised-images variable size parameter not working (or webpack loading issue?)

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I created a component where I just want to define an image source, and specify an array (prop name sizes for optimisation.

If I declare:

```
<source
  :data-srcset="require(`~/assets/images/${src}?resize&size=${150}`)"
  type="image/png"
  :media="`(max-width: ${maxWidth}px)`"
  />
```

Everything goes fine.
However, if I change the 150 with a variable size, I get a console error.
Example:

```
<source
  :data-srcset="require(`~/assets/images/${src}?resize&size=${size}`)"
  type="image/png"
  :media="`(max-width: ${maxWidth}px)`"
  />
```

The error:

```
Error: Cannot find module './image.jpg?resize&size=150&format=webp'
    at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./assets/images sync recursive ^\.\/.*&format=webp$
```

The image.jpg is there in my /assets/images/ directory. It is valid, since the only thing I changed is de size parameter to a variable value.

Here is the full code for the component I'm trying to create:

```
<template>
  <figure class="picture">
    <picture>
      <template v-for="(maxWidth, size) in Object.entries(sizes)">
        <source
          :data-srcset="
            require(`~/assets/images/${src}?resize&size=${150}&format=webp`)
          "
          type="image/webp"
          :media="`(max-width: ${maxWidth}px)`"
        />
        <source
          :data-srcset="require(`~/assets/images/${src}?resize&size=${150}`)"
          type="image/png"
          :media="`(max-width: ${maxWidth}px)`"
        />
      </template>

      <source
        :data-srcset="
          require(`~/assets/images/${src}?resize&size=${450}&format=webp`)
        "
        type="image/webp"
      />
      <source
        :data-srcset="require(`~/assets/images/${src}?resize&size=${450}`)"
        type="image/png"
      />

      <img
        :data-src="require(`~/assets/images/${src}`)"
        class="lazyload"
        :alt="alt"
      />
    </picture>
  </figure>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    src: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    sizes: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({
        768: 150,
      }),
    },
    defaultSize: {
      type: Number,
      default: 450,
    },
    alt: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

And I followed the following guide for lazysizes + nuxt-optimised-images:
https://dev.to/ignore_you/minify-generate-webp-and-lazyload-images-in-your-vue-nuxt-application-1ilm

Comment: You didn't need to use the webp like this: "image.png?webp"? and note "format=webp" according to the docs: https://github.com/juliomrqz/nuxt-optimized-images/blob/develop/docs/usage.md#webp

Comment: The part where the webp is generated looks like its all working. I believe there are 2 options to specify this. Either ```?webp``` or ```?format=webp```